# Attachments working intermittently

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am having issues with my phpMailer script. I can email from the script, I can even send attachments from the script. However, it only works SOMETIMES and not at other times. I tried changing servers and I have the same issues so I am assuming that it is a coding issue.

when It does not work, the emails still go thorough but it is stripped from any attachments.

The attachments are definitely making it onto the server in the same location and then this script is sent an array of attachments which it then adds onto the message.

In one instance the same code and same files will send and not send! Very confusing! Usually some will send for awhile and then some will not for awhile.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

class Mailer extends PHPMailer {

    public function copyToFolder($folderPath) {
        $message = $this->MIMEHeader . $this->MIMEBody;
        $path = "INBOX" . (isset($folderPath) && !is_null($folderPath) ? ".".$folderPath : ""); // Location to save the email

        $imapStream = imap_open("{mail.server.com:143/novalidate-cert}" . $path , $this->Username, $this->Password) or die(mysql_error());

        imap_append($imapStream, "{mail.server.com:143/novalidate-cert}" . $path, $message)or die(mysql_error());

        }
        imap_close($imapStream);
    }
}

$from = $_POST['from'];
$username = $from; 

$grabPassword = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `email_pw_db` WHERE `emailaddress` = '$from'");
$fetchPassword = mysql_fetch_assoc($grabPassword);
$password = $fetchPassword['password'];

$company = $_POST['to'];
$toemail = $_POST['toemail'];
$from = $username;
$namefrom = $_POST['from'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$cc = trim($_POST['cc']);
$bcc = trim($_POST['bcc']);
$message = $_POST['body'];;
$attachments = $_POST['attachments'];



$mail = new Mailer();

$body = $message;
/*Create a new email*/
$mail = new Mailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'mail.server.com';
$mail->Username = $username;
$mail->Password = $password;
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->AddReplyTo($from,$namefrom);
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent, reduces SMTP overhead
$mail->SetFrom($from, $namefrom);

$mail->AddReplyTo($from,$namefrom);

$address = $toemail;
$mail->AddAddress($address, $company);

$mail->Subject    = $subject;

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; 

$mail->MsgHTML($body);
if($cc!=''){
$mail->addCC($cc);
}

//CC EMAILS//
$breakOutCC = explode(',', $cc);

$countBreakOut = count($breakOutCC);
$i = 0; 
while($i <$countBreakOut)
{
$mail->addCC($breakOutCC[$i]);

$i++;
}

$breakOutBCC = explode(',', $bcc);

$countBreakOutBCC = count($breakOutBCC); 

$i = 0;

while($i <$countBreakOutBCC)
{

$mail->addBCC($breakOutBCC[$i]);

$i++;
}

$breakoutAttachments = explode(',', $attachments);
$countAttachments = count($breakoutAttachments); 
$i = 0; 

while($i <$countAttachments)
{
$mail->AddAttachment("attachments/email_attachments/".$breakoutAttachments[$i]);      

$i++;
}

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  $errorMessage = $mail->ErrorInfo; 
  header( 'Location: email-software.php?dialog=Whoops Something Happened- '.$errorMessage ) ;
} else {
    //$mail->copyToFolder(); //save email

$mail->copyToFolder("Sent"); // Will save into Sent folder
$attachments = $_POST['attachments'];

$breakoutAttachments = explode(',', $attachments);

$countAttachments = count($breakoutAttachments); 

$i = 0; 

while($i <$countAttachments)
{
unlink("attachments/email_attachments/".$breakoutAttachments[$i]);    

$i++;
}


 header( 'Location: email-software.php?dialog=email sent' ) ;
}

?>
```

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like checking if your attachment files actually exist and are readable? Checked the return value from AddAttachment?

Comment: I checked the server for the images and they are definitely on there and exist...and are readable. As for the return value do you mean like this...

$success = $mail->AddAttachment("attachments/email_attachments/".$breakoutAttachments[$i]);

Comment: If it's really this intermittent, I'd suggest you use a debugger and set appropriate breakpoints to catch it in the act. There is rather too much code in your example to debug - cut it down to eliminate sources of error.

Comment: @ExecutiveCloser did you ever get to the bottom of this? I am having the same problem myself now. Whenever I troubleshoot, attachments are fine, but then emails go out to clients and attachments fail. Same files, same script, just as you describe, but attachments only work intermittently.

Comment: @sunny I actually did get this resolved and my attachments were getting uploaded from local computer to local server and then mailed out. I believe this was due to the file being overwritten/deleted or maybe the reference on the page was not there before sending the page to my mailer script.