# phpmailer attachment failing whenever I execute file with cronjob/mail to outerside clients but works whenever I run script from command line

Tags: php, phpmailer

I upgraded my website emails (sent via AWS SES) to have an HTML format with an attached image a few days ago. I am using PHPMailer. When I do test runs either to an email on my domain or to my personal email - even in high volume - everything runs great.

In contrast, when my cronjob has executed the very same script to mail to other websites users, the file attachment has not gone through most (or possibly all) of the time. Is this likely related to it being a cronjob? I have simulated much higher volume on my own than I actually use when emailing site users, so it's not a volume/rate limiting problem.

It is quite reliably failing when I run from cronjob even though this is a simple php script that has nothing to do with any environmental dependencies. Does anyone have advice for debugging? The only related post I saw was here:

[Attachments working intermittently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420023/phpmailer-attachments-working-intermittently)

Comment: if you run a script with two different users and get different results - its likley a permissions issue

Comment: @Dagon no, it's the same user in both cases.

Comment: @sunny, can you post the code?? I mean... cronjob, command line script, php script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely to be a path problem - cron jobs do not set a PATH environment var by default, so set one in your cron script, or use absolute paths for everything.

For example if you say:

```
php myscript.php
```

It may not find the php binary or your script, or your attachment, so do something like this:

```
PATH=/usr/bin
php myscript.php
```

or

```
/usr/bin/php /path/to/myscript.php
```

You need to tell us exactly what the error is - "It doesn't work" isn't useful information.

Comment: you were exactly right. It's funny though - I did lots of PHP include statements using relative paths, and that's been working fine. But this adding attachment did not work until now when I added the absolute path. Thanks a lot!